# SSIS - Data Flow not executing

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

I running a huge select in a view using a lot of joins in giant tables inside a Data Flow.

The main task seems to be executed without errors as it becomes green, however when I look inside of it none of the sub tasks were executed (Select and Insert).

Searching for a while I found some posts saying that if no rows are returned in 30 seconds the query will fail. But I don't see any error while debugging the project.

Is is true that if no row is returned within 30 seconds I'll have error?
If so, is there a way o prevent it?

I don't have the option to add indexes to the table as I only have read rights.

I'm using SSIS 2008 by the way.

Thank you!

Comment: This is all about where you have your 'tasks' and what control flow they have. When you say 'look inside it', what are you talking about? A data flow or a sequence container?

Comment: Ni Nick, I have one Sequence Container and inside it I have one Data Flow. The data flow becomes green after running the project however when I open the data flow, nothing inside was executed, no error, no warning or success massage.

Comment: What does the progress tab look like. Does it say the data flow source was started? Figure 10 on this page shows what it should roughly look like: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/debugging-data-flow-in-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: Are you certain the package has completed? The progress tab will give you an idea. Also it will say 'click here to debug' down the bottom when complete. Perhaps its waiting for something at the source but usually it at least turns yellow.

Comment: Yes, the package execution is completed. I can see in the logs that the Task began end ended without error. But it takes around one second only to execute the task, I I run the same query in the database it will take around 7 minutes.

Comment: So can you see the _source_ starting and ending - can you see it listed in there or not?